# ggplot2: Bars between x-axis ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2, axes

The data I need to visualise contains passenger loads on a train between 4 stations. The data is provided in an ordered fashion, ie. between Station A and V there are 432 passengers on the train, between V and B 543 and so on. In the coding example I have ploted the data with ggplot2.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~Station, ~Passengers,
              "A", 432,
              "V", 543,
              "B", 435,
              "Q", 0)

df$Station <- factor(df$Station, levels=unique(df$Station))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Station, y = Passengers)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

The problem: 
I would like to position the x-axis ticks and Station names between the bars. The goal is to shift the bars 50% to the right.

Comment: Take a look at the [nudge](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_nudge.html) functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `position_nudge` to adjust the bars:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Station, y = Passengers)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_nudge(x = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: I knew that the answer would be embarrassingly short! Thank you

Comment: You had already done the hard part--getting your factor in correct order with the "missing" level included.

Comment: Is there a way to combine the positioning commands: position_nudge and position_stack? I haven't found anything helpful.. I probably should submit a new question.

Comment: Yup, sounds like a new question. I don't know how to do it off-hand.

Answer (score 0):

With the newest version of [`ggplot 3.4.0`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases/tag/v3.4.0) you can use the argument just in geom_col or geom_bar:

> Adjustment for column placement. Set to 0.5 by default, meaning that
> columns will be centered about axis breaks. Set to 0 or 1 to place
> columns to the left/right of axis breaks. Note that this argument may
> have unintended behaviour when used with alternative positions, e.g.
> position_dodge().

Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~Station, ~Passengers,
              "A", 432,
              "V", 543,
              "B", 435,
              "Q", 0)

df$Station <- factor(df$Station, levels=unique(df$Station))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Station, y = Passengers)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", just = 1.05)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>